# How to make typography hi-res for web?

Tags: typography, resolution

Suppose I'm going to make a typography poster (or whatever) that's going to be posted for advertisement in, let's say, Facebook, ***how high should the resolution be? Any specific numbers I should have to remember?***

I've been struggling with this for so long HAHAHA and I couldn't find anything. Every time I save it as jpeg and post the image online, the resolution becomes soooo low. The edges of the font becomes softer, and squiggly lines appear on the side of it. And everything just looks.. Softer.

It frustrates me because whenever I see other typography art, they're all so sharp and clean and mine just looks like crap.

Help me please D:

Comment: First of all: could you provide a sample and… what's your tool? Ps?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with facebook but doesn't the content-area of facebook have a fixed default width? You would probably do best sticking to that width (height is less important because people can scroll down). The quality decrease you mention is either because the image is scaled down (or up, more likely) or becasue the site does that, in order to preserve server space.

Comment: I don't use the myface or facetimes but AFAIK, Facebook does alter the quality on uploaded jpg files it increases compression, which will kill quality. Also yes, reducing an image will tend to blur it a little.

Comment: The heart of this question seems to be compression used by Facebook.  Do any of [these answers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3134/690) help?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Facebook only allows JPG images and, on top of that, Facebook re-compresses JPG images.

The issue you are having is likely less to do with the particular resolution of the image you are creating and more to do with JPG compression--which typically makes any text blurry.

I may be wrong about the JPG-only part, though. If I am, try uploading your images as GIF or PNG files. The compression that GIF and PNG uses will likely produce a sharper image for type than JPG does.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to save poster in **png**.
- May be you try to upload too big image, that downsampled on server automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this ONLY for facebook, determine the max width or height available to you and then make your image exactly that dimension.

If you are doing this for yourself, then do it however you like and then export a reduced size version with the right pixel dimensions for facebook, then upload that copy to facebook.

The advantage of this is that you are able to tweak it, sharpen it etc before you upload it. Export to PNG-24 if possible (if facebook supports that of course), since this will preserve colors and the text will look as crisp (virtually) as in the original. Jpeg tends to blur and smear areas of solid color because of the nature of the compression algorithm.

Finally, once you upload the image to facebook, save the uploaded image back to your computer and compare it to the one you uploaded. Look at the file size, the file type, etc. This might will help you figure out how it changes during uplaod and then decide on how to work with the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Many folks used to resort to automatically answering **72dpi**, as that was the old school monitor resolution. Now monitor resolutions are much higher. If you view a jpeg in your web browser that is too big to be seen at 100%, most of them automatically scale them down to fit the whole image. So **there is no hard fast answer on the resolution question** without knowing more about the end use. I will tell you that there is no reason to go higher than **150dpi**.

Jpeg compression is not ideal for continuous tones and solids. It's good for photos. If you are doing text and line art, PNG is a good format. GIF is outdated, PNG has superseded it in pretty much all aspects outside of animation.

Comment: The DPI setting in your photo editing software has absolutely no bearing on the pixel dimensions for web images.

Comment: While a 2 inch by 3 inch photo will display at 2"x3" in the browser whether it is 72dpi or 150dpi, that does not mean it has no effect. The higher resolution will display crisper and have more detail. This is especially noticable in high resolution displays like the Retina display on the iPad.

Comment: For now, photos on the web are still primarily pixel based dimensions. 2" is somewhat meaningless (yes, you can use it as a measurement in CSS, but that's atypical). For Retina displays, you need to exactly double the pixel dimensions, and then tell Retina devices that you are using a double sized image. Again, the dpi setting is irrelevant.

Comment: And I'm saying, for on screen graphics, there is no dpi setting.

Comment: @DA01 I concede, you are correct. Dpi settings in photoshop should have no effect on how a web browser renders an image.