# Photo distorts terribly on Facebook

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, resolution, image-quality, file-format

I've designed a logo which looks high res in photoshop. But really distorts in Facebook. I understand that Facebook converts the image, but compared to similar logos, it looks bad. Any ways around this?

Comment: For the quality there isn't many things you can do! Try PNG or jpg at 12...for the colors choose sRGB as color profile.

Comment: **I think this question will give you some tips: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images**

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will use their own technique for compressing uploaded images to use in thumbnails. To avoid the noise and distortion that occurs after this resize the best thing you could do is to create another source for the logo in 160x160 pixels and upload that to Facebook to use as the profile picture.

If you create it in the correct size from scratch it will not be subject to poor compressing techniques.