# Purple text on dark background too blurry when uploading to facebook (saved as png)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, png, compression

I'm going nuts here. I'll try to be straight to the point.

I'm using Photoshop CC and have this dark background image for a poster with some text info. Sentences in white, three infos in purple, which I already chose from the web color palete.
The thing is, I need to use this poster for the web, I've saved it, tried and checked and rechecked it all, and everytime the purple text is all blurry and pixelated when uploading on Facebook. The white text is ok. I didn't want to put all text in white and have it solved by that, it seems to me it will look too boring for this design. So, I'm looking forward to any tips or possible solutions I might not have tried to get this text unblurred and unpixelated! Here it goes:

- the file mode is set s-rgb, 72dpi, all like it should be
- I'm saving it as png-8 through the save for web option, have tried png-24, gif, with and without transparency, 256 colors, 128 colors, checked and unchecked include color profile, selective, perceptive...
- As Facebook compresses in jpg, I've saved the file as png and then as jpg to see if there was some sort of magic to happen, it just got worse of course.
- I've tried all anti-aliasing options and none
- I've tried small (120k), medium(700k) and large(2m) file sizes, they all have the blurry pixelated outcome on the purple text when uploaded to Facebook. Resized the images through the save for web dialog and the resize from the image menu
- When I try a lighter hue of purple, the blurry gets better, still don't find it good enough and didn't want light colors for this. I've tried many purpleish and magentaish for the record
- I've tried different font types, no change
- I've even put white rectangles to background the purple text to see if it would work better, and the answer is no, it doesn't
- Tracking, fractional widths on, off, all tried out

Some examples of the text on fb: [image]

So, what am I missing? What else can I try? Is it just an irreparable FB issue? I'm not an Illustrator or any other graphic/image editing software user, but if there is any that could help me with that... I'm becoming a fan.

Comment: What's the size in "pixels"? I know that something, the "resizing" tools online mess with creations.

Comment: Facebook do terrible things to images. This post might help? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26358/photo-distorts-terribly-on-facebook

Comment: @Larme, I tried different sizes and dimensions, including 720, 960 like the link boblet shared. Redesigned the whole thing from scratch in the exact dimensions for Facebook, it didn't help me with the purple. Actually I found better visualization when resizing my big file in photoshop to the 720px Fb requires than the done-small one. It was a matter of letting go of the saturated purple to the lighter one and preferring more blurry or more pixelated.

Comment: Here's what I got to:
s24.postimg.org/kr84jxyk5/testesforum.png It seems Photoshop created some sort of contrast with the background by adding a lighter contour to the letters when I resized the file. That helped with the sharpness against the blurry effect, it did not vanquished the pixelation though.

Thank you for the reply, Larme, @boblet. I think I'll have to deal with that as my final outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here isn't as much on your end as Facebook's. Imagine 500,000,000 users, all with Hi-res banners and profile pics... there's a SERIOUS amount of compression/degradation that they apply unfortunately. There's ways you can minimize it, by starting with Hi-Q stuff out the gate, but the artifacts are somewhat unavoidable.