# How to get a non pixelated illustration upload to social media (mostly FB)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur, compression, pixelation

Intro: I'm not a GD, but bear with me. 
I've been doing digital illustrations for a while and never had an issue with posting them anywhere, until this year.
I keep getting all my illustrations sort of blurred/pixelated every time I upload them to most social medias.
I use Illustrator CC. Most of the time I create my work on a CMYK file (just in case if I ever want it to print it), 300 ppi, align to pixel grid and then export it on RGB. Mostly on square format (20x20cms, I changed it to 1200px x 1200px as someone suggested those measurments me for fb)
This is driving me nuts. Believe me I've tried everything (save for web, save for microsoft office, jpg, png, different sizes and resolutions according to fb, tw, pinterest...) The only place they look great are tumblr or behance, since they don't compress anything, so far.
I'm ready to try everything one more time, for the sake of my images looking sharp.

[image: Here's an example of what I'm suffering. Left one is the fb uploaded version. Right one the original, how it should look.]

Here's an example of what I'm suffering. Left one is the fb uploaded version. Right one the original, how it should look.

Help a girl out!
Thanks

Cecily

Comment: Hi CN R, I would check out these relevant question as well - [Facebook: Ways to preserve image quality of uploaded images?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images)

Comment: Facebook re-optimize your images, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Hi people. Thanks for the answers. Sorry for the duplicate question, but I've asked it again 'cause I've already read all the threads of it none of those solutions have worked for me. So here I am, still battling the fb compression. There must be something I/we can do since I've seen illustrations uploaded without this disturbing blurriness.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Facebook compresses any images uploaded to save on their storage space (which makes sense, since there are millions of photos on there). No matter what you do, Facebook will resample it in the end and you'll end up with those JPG artifacts that are bugging you so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Facebook compresses like crazy. I've tried uploading very hi res images there and they still compress it. When I post images to facebook I also add a link to a better looking online version of that same graphic/work (Tumblr, Behance, Deviant Art etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend uploading it as a PNG - it seems to hold the quality better, specifically for Facebook.

Just make sure it's under 1MB or Facebook may convert them back to JPG.

Comment: FB=? I suppose Facebook, but acronyms make it not easier to read your text. Please write it out.

Comment: Yes, Facebook. Sorry for the confusion. Noted for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Just touching on the other answers but with more info. In a nutshell Facebook has a shitty compression system so if you upload an image with only a handful of colours you will notice the artefacts around the edges of the content in the image.

You're less likely to notice the lower quality if you upload a JPEG with thousands of colours as it will "blend" better.