# Why does my image appear low-quality on the internet?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality

I've created the following image in Photoshop (500x500 res). **Each layer in the image is made with the shape tool.**

[image: My image]

The image I've created looks great on my personal device and in Photoshop. However, I noticed that when uploading the avatar to Twitter and GitHub--it doesn't look good at all. Below is what the image looks like on both.

[image: My image on GitHub]
[image: My image on Twitter]

The edges appear very jagged and the image looks dull overall. **Here is what I have tried doing so far but it has not solved the issue:**

- Exporting the image in PNG-24 through "Save for Web"
- Rasterizing the layers, merging the layers into one
- Switching to JPEG format

Does anyone know how I can improve the quality when uploading it to websites as an avatar? Is the original image too low resolution? Do I have to change the resampling method when scaling it up or down? Just some thoughts I had if it helps. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's because social networking sites convert images to JPEG and apply aggressive compression to keep the file size small. [See this related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images/) - it's about the same thing with Facebook, but it's the same problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! That's very good information. I randomly tried decreasing the resolution to 300x300 (resample with bicubic sharpener) and exporting as PNG-24. While not perfect, I found that it looks better on these websites and is not noticeable.

Comment: I've also find if you convert to JPEG, and add a moderate amount of compression instead of allowing the social media site to do it automatically, that can also help improve the quality a bit.

Comment: Note that when you **upload** an image to 90% of web sites, many will *post-process* the image and compress it again. What you see *after* the upload is rarely the actual image you uploaded. In other words, it's not like copying the image to another device. The image gets re-saved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this will completely 'fix' the issue, as the social media re-compressions are pretty agressive, but just a note on size reduction.

Always test Bilinear for a reduction. The received wisdom is always that Bicubic Sharper is best, but I don't think it always is.

Compare these - bilinear left, bicubic sharper right…

[image] [image]

No contest for me, bilinear wins hands down.

Also, consider GIF for something like this, built of flat colours [without resizing].

[image]